# If $(V, \langle,\rangle)$ is a $4$ dim vector space, then show that the set of all compatible complex structures consists of two copies of $S^2$.

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry

> If $(V, \langle,\rangle)$ is a four-dimensional Euclidean vector space, then show that the set of all compatible complex structures consists of two copies of $S^2$.

I'm quite new to complex differential geometry and this feels a bit weird to me as if we let $A$ denote the set of all complex structures of $V$, then $A = \{I : V \to V \mid I^2 = -\operatorname{id}, \langle I(v), I(w)\rangle = \langle v, w\rangle \}$ and for some reason this should consist of two copies of $S^2$?

I know that we also have $I \in O((V, \langle,\rangle))$, but this ain't helping that much either.

By compatible we mean that $\langle I(v), I(w)\rangle = \langle v, w\rangle$.

Comment: What does *compatible* mean in this context?

Comment: @LeeMosher I assume that's the $\langle I(v),I(w)\rangle=\langle v,w\rangle$ that OP mentioned.

Comment: That might be correct, but perhaps the OP could confirm and edit for clarity.

Comment: Fun fact: we can view $\Bbb R^4$ as the quaternions $\Bbb H$, and then the compatible complex structures correspond to left or right multiplication by unit quaternions (corresponding to the two copies of $S^2$).

Comment: @elemelons Why not write that up as an answer? Also, is there a quick way to see that every compatible structure corresponds to a unit quaternion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note $I$ is not just orthogonal but also skew. That is, if we replace $\mathbf{w}$ with $-I(\mathbf{w})$ in the compatibility condition we get $\langle I(\mathbf{v}),\mathbf{w}\rangle=-\langle\mathbf{v},I(\mathbf{w})\rangle$. In particular, this means $\mathbf{v}\perp I(\mathbf{v})$ are perpendicular for any vector $\mathbf{v}$.

Some geometry background. Cartan-Diedonne / the real Spectral Theorem tells us any orthogonal transformation is block-diagonalizable to a bunch of 2D rotations and possibly a 1D reflection in orthogonal subspaces. If all of the angles are the same, this it is called an *isoclonic* rotation. In even dimension, we can distinguish between "left" and "right" isoclinic rotations by how the orientations of the 2D subspaces (oriented so that the angles of rotation are convex) "add up" to the orientation of the overall Euclidean space (imagine picking ordered bases for the 2D subspaces, then joining them into a larger ordered basis).

"Infinitessimal" orthogonal transformations (i.e. skew or antisymmetric matrices, from the orthogonal lie algebra) are block-diagonalizable as homotheties & right-angle rotations in orthogonal 2D subspaces. (Compare with multiplication-by-$e^{i\theta}$ versus multiplication-by-$i\theta$ in the complex plane.) So right-angle isoclinic rotations are exactly those transformations which are elements of both the orthogonal group *and* its lie algebra; these are precisely the compatible complex structures.

Pick a unit vector $p\in\mathbb{R}^4$. Then $I(p)$ is a unit vector in the unit sphere of $p$'s 3D orthogonal complement. If we restrict to left-isoclinic $I$'s, the value of $I(p)\in S^2$ determines $I$ completely, and similarly for right-isoclinic. These are the two copies of $S^2$ which parametrize the $I$s.

If you're familiar with quaternions, we can describe the situation nicely with them. By "extending linearly" from the multiplication table for $\{1,\mathbf{i},\mathbf{j},\mathbf{k}\}$ , we can see the product of vectors has scalar and vector components given by $\mathbf{uv}=-\mathbf{u}\cdot\mathbf{v}+\mathbf{u}\times\mathbf{v}$. This tells us a number of things: the sqrts of $+1$ are $\pm1$; the sqrts of $-1$ are the unit vectors; quaternions commute iff their vector parts are parallel; quaternions "anticommute" iff they are orthogonal vectors. (The inner product is $\mathrm{Re}(\overline{x}y)$, and the norm is multiplicative.)

In particular, given any unit vector $\mathbf{u}$, we can extend it to an oriented orthonormal basis $\{1,\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v},\mathbf{w}\}$. Computing the matrix for the linear transformations $L_\mathbf{u}(x)=\mathbf{u}x$ and $R_\mathbf{u}(x)=x\mathbf{u}$ with respect to this basis, we see they are left and right isoclinic complex structures respectively. We infer any left or right isoclinic complex structure $I$ is just $L_\mathbf{u}$ or $R_\mathbf{u}$ with $\mathbf{u}=I(1)$.